# Finding orthonormal basis of a polynomial (without a given dimension)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I have the following problem:

> Find an orthonormal basis of the plane $x_1 + 6x_2 - x_3 = 0$.

I am suspecting that this problem is asking me to apply Gram-Schmidt so I can get $q'_1$ and $q'_2$.

Am I right? Is it safe to assume that this is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$? The problem is that I am not given a space, therefore I don't know how to compute my vectors.

Any help on how to get started or which path should I follow its appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: You're right. Find a basis (it is a two dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$) and then use Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: I compute it and I get ( 1/sqrt(38), 3( sqrt( 2/19 ) ), -1/sqrt(38) ) as seen here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gram+schmidt+%7B%7B1%2C6%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D&x=0&y=0 After that I dont know how to proceed. Gram Schmidt the basis? How?

Comment: Added you an analytic answer down below. Make sure you check it out and ask anything you may not understand. If the answer fits you, make sure you approve it (and any answer by anyone in the future that fits you) so that the thread goes down as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the vectors : $v_1 = (1,0,-1)$ and $v_2 = (0,1,-6)$, $span[(1,0,-1),(0,1,-6)]$. Apply Gram Schmidt to these two vectors and the answer that you get is the orthonormal basis : $span[(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}),(-\frac{3}{\sqrt{19}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{19}},-\frac{3}{\sqrt{19}})]. $

Comment: Apparently, it is wrong

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tij0k.png